# Anchor tag appending field value to current url instead of just navigating to field value

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a model with a field `website_link`.

```html
class Partner(models.Model):
    website_link = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

And I access it in the template like so

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
  {% if instance.logo %}</a>
  <!-- website link just gets appended to the end of current url for some reason-->
  <a href="{{ instance.website_link }}"><img src='{{ instance.logo.url }}' class='img-responsive' alt=""></a>
  {% endif %}
 </div>
```

When I call this in the template inside of an anchor tag the link navigates to the current url with the website_link appended to the end.

So if `instance.website_url = www.partnerone.com` instead of going to `www.partnerone.com` it goes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/partners/partner-one/www.partnerone.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like some links stored in your `website_link` are relative urls. If they don't start with `//` or `http://` or equivalent, you will get the result you're seeing.